# How can I change from Ubuntu 15.04 Daily Build to stable?

Tags: downgrade, daily-build

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 Daily Build and I would like to change my system so that it is stable. I imagine this could involve downgrading some packages. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to do anything.

If you installed a daily build of Ubuntu 15.04 before release, it converted itself to stable in case you installed updates.

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for your help on this. So, what then is the difference between an installation using an image from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and an image from [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/)?

Comment: The daily build has current updates included, the other one was frozen on release, and updates can be installed after installation.

Comment: I checked it and see that daily builds were made only till release. Then they stopped updating it. So there is no difference now.

Comment: But before there used to be daily builds with updates included. Anyway there is nothing to do now.